# How to filter java logs using logstash?

Tags: java, logstash

I need to filter only java fatal logs and put that logs into elasticsearch index using logstash pipeline.

I put logs to an elasticsearch index. but it has all the logs(ex- info,debug).

**Sample log entry:**

```
2019-05-06 14:37:23 DEBUG Scheduler : Starting Scheduler... 2019-05-06 14:37:24 INFO Scheduler : Quartz scheduler started
```

Comment: What kind of input are you talking about? Put some sample log entry formats in the question please.

Comment: As well as sample logs, what logstash command(s) have you tried so far?

Comment: @SachithDickwella this is some logs  2019-05-06 14:37:23 DEBUG Scheduler : Starting Scheduler...
2019-05-06 14:37:24 INFO  Scheduler : Quartz scheduler started.

Comment: @lakminachathurya, Update the question with your existing pipeline config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your log entries could be something like this.

**Ex:**

```
2019-04-23 10:12:10 INFO - 12345 - SQL - sqlQuery1 - 12
2019-04-23 10:12:10 FATAL - 12345 - SQL - sqlQuery2 - 34
2019-04-23 10:12:10 INFO - 12345 - TASK_END - end
```

For this input, Logstash `filter` could be something like this;

```
filter {
   grok {
     match => [ "message" => "%{NOTSPACE:datetime} - %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} - %{NOTSPACE:taskid} - %{NOTSPACE:logger} - %{WORD:label}( - %{INT:duration:int})?" ]
   }

   if [loglevel] =~ "FATAL" {
     drop { }
   }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
          hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
          index => "indexfatal-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

I'm mapping the input entries using `grok` plugin and then check and drop non-FATAL entries to exclude them from the index.

This might require slight nudge to work with your logs.

Comment: Even simpler would be to do just `if [message] =~ /FATAL/ { drop{} }`

Comment: @baudsp, I didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Sachith Dickwella. its solved the problem